# Proof by Induction for $\frac{1}{1\cdot3}+\frac{1}{3\cdot5}+...+\frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}=\frac{n}{2n+1}$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: induction

I got stuck at a certain point at this question. I first took a base case of $n=1$ which gave $\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{3}$ showing that the formula holds.

Next, I take $n=k$ assuming that it is true. This gives$$\frac{1}{1\cdot3}+\frac{1}{3\cdot5}+...+\frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}=\frac{k}{2k+1}$$

Now, I want to show that $n=k+1$ is also true giving: $$\frac{1}{1\cdot3}+\frac{1}{3\cdot5}+...+\frac{1}{(2k+1)(2k+3)}=\frac{k+1}{2k+3}$$

From here, I replaced the sequence before $n=k+1$ with $\frac{k}{2k+1}$. This would then give: $$\frac{k}{2k+1}+\frac{1}{(2k+1)(2k+3)}=\frac{k+1}{2k+3}$$

From here, I used the LHS to prove that it would equal the RHS, so I multiplied the first term $\frac{k}{2k+1}$ with $2k+3$ so that there is a common denominator on the LHS. This results in $$\frac{(2k+1)(k+1)+1}{(2k+1)(2k+3)}=\frac{2k^2+3k+1+1}{(2k+1)(2k+3)}=\frac{(2k+1)^2+1}{(2k+1)(2k+3)}$$

At this point, what I would automatically do is to realise that $2k+1$ cancels on the numerator and denominator leaving us with: $$\frac{2k+2}{2k+3}=\frac{2(k+1)}{2k+3}$$

I feel that I am very close to the solution but I cannot get the LHS to equal the RHS.

**Edit**: after taking the base case for $n=k+1$ where $k=1$, I find that I get $\frac{1}{3\cdot5}\ne\frac{2}{5}$. Hence the the formula does not hold for $n=k+1$.

Comment: You need to prove that if the $n=k$ case is true, then the $n=k+1$ is true. To do this, you can assume the $n=k$ case is true, but you cannot assume the $n=k+1$ case is true, since that is what you need to **prove**.

Comment: $\frac{k}{2k+1}+\frac{1}{(2k+1)(2k+3)}=\frac{k(2k+3)}{(2k+1)(2k+3)}+\frac{1}{(2k+1)(2k+3)}=\frac{k(2k+3)+1}{(2k+1)(2k+3)}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\frac{1}{(2i-1)(2i+1)}
&= \sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{1}{(2i-1)(2i+1)}+\frac{1}{(2k+1)(2k+3)}\\[1em]
&=\frac{k}{2k+1}+\frac{1}{(2k+1)(2k+3)}\\[1em]
&= \frac{k(2k+3)+1}{(2k+1)(2k+3)}\\[1em]
&=\frac{(2k+1)(k+1)}{(2k+1)(2k+3)}\\[1em]
&=\frac{k+1}{2k+3}.
\end{align*}
$$
If you don't know why this is more of an answer than a hint, then I'd encourage you to read up more on induction and what proofs by induction are (largely) supposed to look like.

Answer (score 0):

In your induction step, you should prove that

$$\frac{1}{1\cdot3}+\frac{1}{3\cdot5}+...+\frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}+\frac{1}{(2(n+1)-1)(2(n+1)+1)}=\frac{n+1}{2(n+1)+1}$$
**given** your induction hypothesis.